# favicon.ico not found error?

Tags: web, spring-security, http-status-code-404, favicon

I have an application that uses Spring Security 3 runs on Tomcat. I didn't define any favicon for my website however when I run my application from my IDE `sometimes` after I login from my login pages it redirects my page to:

```
http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico
```

and says:

```
404 Not Found
```

There is a topic here: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?100901-redirect-to-favicon.ico however I didn't define a favicon.ico does Spring Security 3 wants it by default(if yes, why it happens sometimes?)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is the explanation:

> The issue is, when the browser cache is empty and a user comes in,
>   here is what happens:
>
> - the user requests URL "/". This URL is cached.
> - the browser makes a requests to "/favicon.ico". This URL becomes
>     the new URL where to redirect to upon authentication.
> - the user posts the login form and is redirected to "/favicon.ico".
>
> To fix this, you need to set "/favicon.ico" as being a non-secured
>   resources:
>
> ```
> <intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
> ```

Taken from: http://blog.idm.fr/2010/09/spring-security-redirecting-to-faviconico.html

Comment: I stumbled upon this Q&A when trying to figure this out for my Grails app. I'm using an altered URLMappings configuration to work with my AngularJS/Grails app, where Grails is mostly a REST backend. Spring Security is used for ajax auth and I've run into this issue in Chrome as well. For Grails users, add an entry into UrlMappings like: "/favicon.ico"(controller: "home", action: "ajaxSuccess") where ajaxSuccess contains a redirect to the place you might want to send the user to on auth success.

Comment: There is a good description of this issue here: http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/favicon.shtml

Answer (score 0):

For Grails 3.0.11 & Spring Security Core 3.0.2, add "IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" in application.groovy in the section:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
...
..
.
[pattern: '/favicon.ico',      access: ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']]
]
```