# GroovyPagesException: Error applying layout

Tags: grails, layout, jetty, gsp, eofexception

I got stuck with that problem. I found a lot of similar questions, but they have differed yet from my situation (maybe I missed something?).

So, here is a stacktrace from production server:

```
    2016-11-10 04:28:59,148 [qtp1265210847-22] ERROR StackTrace Full Stack Trace:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error applying layout : frontend
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.GroovyPageView.rethrowRenderException(GroovyPageView.java:179)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.SpringMVCViewDecorator.render(SpringMVCViewDecorator.java:78)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsLayoutView.renderTemplate(GrailsLayoutView.java:61)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.AbstractGrailsView.renderWithinGrailsWebRequest(AbstractGrailsView.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.AbstractGrailsView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractGrailsView.java:33)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(GrailsDispatcherServlet.java:388)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1686)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1088)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:74)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(UrlMappingUtils.java:178)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(UrlMappingUtils.java:144)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(UrlMappingUtils.java:135)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlMappingsFilter.java:216)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.medgreat.web.security.AnonymousAjaxRequestFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAjaxRequestFilter.groovy:31)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1088)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.GroovyPageView.createGroovyPageException(GroovyPageView.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.GroovyPageView.handleException(GroovyPageView.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.GroovyPageView.renderTemplate(GroovyPageView.java:75)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.AbstractGrailsView.renderWithinGrailsWebRequest(AbstractGrailsView.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.AbstractGrailsView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractGrailsView.java:33)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.SpringMVCViewDecorator.render(SpringMVCViewDecorator.java:69)
    ... 107 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.RuntimeIOException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ResponseWriter.isOpen(ResponseWriter.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ResponseWriter.write(ResponseWriter.java:202)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper$SaveContextPrintWriter.write(SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.java:236)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer$SingleOutputWriter.write(StreamCharBuffer.java:2478)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer$StreamCharBufferWriter.write(StreamCharBuffer.java:1096)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer$StreamCharBufferWriter.write(StreamCharBuffer.java:1075)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.GrailsPrintWriter.write(GrailsPrintWriter.java:309)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.GrailsPrintWriterAdapter.write(GrailsPrintWriterAdapter.java:147)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsRoutablePrintWriter.write(GrailsRoutablePrintWriter.java:241)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.support.encoding.WriterEncodedAppender.write(WriterEncodedAppender.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.support.encoding.AbstractEncodedAppender.append(AbstractEncodedAppender.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer$CharBufferChunk.encodeTo(StreamCharBuffer.java:1765)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer.encodeTo(StreamCharBuffer.java:2852)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.support.encoding.AbstractEncodedAppender.append(AbstractEncodedAppender.java:207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer$StreamCharBufferSubChunk.encodeTo(StreamCharBuffer.java:2108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer.encodeTo(StreamCharBuffer.java:2852)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.support.encoding.AbstractEncodedAppender.append(AbstractEncodedAppender.java:207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.support.encoding.ChainedEncoders.chainStreamingEncode(ChainedEncoders.java:87)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.support.encoding.ChainedEncoders.chainEncode(ChainedEncoders.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer$StreamCharBufferSubChunk.encodeTo(StreamCharBuffer.java:2111)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer.encodeTo(StreamCharBuffer.java:2852)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.support.encoding.AbstractEncodedAppender.append(AbstractEncodedAppender.java:207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.support.encoding.ChainedEncoders.chainStreamingEncode(ChainedEncoders.java:87)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.support.encoding.ChainedEncoders.chainEncode(ChainedEncoders.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer$StreamCharBufferSubChunk.encodeTo(StreamCharBuffer.java:2111)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer.encodeTo(StreamCharBuffer.java:2852)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.support.encoding.AbstractEncodedAppender.append(AbstractEncodedAppender.java:207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.support.encoding.ChainedEncoders.chainStreamingEncode(ChainedEncoders.java:87)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.support.encoding.ChainedEncoders.chainEncode(ChainedEncoders.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer$StreamCharBufferSubChunk.encodeTo(StreamCharBuffer.java:2111)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer.encodeTo(StreamCharBuffer.java:2852)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer.writeToEncodedAppender(StreamCharBuffer.java:633)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer.writeTo(StreamCharBuffer.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer.writeTo(StreamCharBuffer.java:578)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.GrailsPrintWriter.write(GrailsPrintWriter.java:489)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.GrailsPrintWriter.leftShift(GrailsPrintWriter.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.SitemeshTagLib.captureTagContent(SitemeshTagLib.groovy:80)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.SitemeshTagLib.captureTagContent(SitemeshTagLib.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.SitemeshTagLib$_closure3.doCall(SitemeshTagLib.groovy:157)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor655.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1123)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage.invokeTagLibClosure(GroovyPage.java:501)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage.invokeTag(GroovyPage.java:419)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage$invokeTag$4.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gsp_medgreatWeb_layoutsfrontend_gsp.run(gsp_medgreatWeb_layoutsfrontend_gsp.groovy:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageWritable.doWriteTo(GroovyPageWritable.java:217)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageWritable.writeTo(GroovyPageWritable.java:128)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.GroovyPageView.renderTemplate(GroovyPageView.java:71)
    ... 111 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:650)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:441)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Utf8HttpWriter.write(Utf8HttpWriter.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ResponseWriter.write(ResponseWriter.java:203)
    ... 164 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:175)
    ... 179 more
```

My custom filter AnonymousAjaxRequestFilter :

```
  try {
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse)
        } catch (AccessDeniedException e) {
            if (ajaxHeader) {
                if (!session) {
                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN)
                } else {
                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN)
                }
            } else {
                throw e
            }
        }
```

seems nothing special.

As I know, this error doesn`t appear to user, but our log files are flooded by this exception.

Any idea of the reason of this exception?

Comment: looks like Grails is trying to apply frontend layout. Check to make sure you have frontend.gsp in your views/layouts folder.

Comment: Sure, I have this layout in my project. Almost all views are based on it.

Comment: it may be the use of `sendError` instead of `setStatus`. Does this only happen when `session` is present? or when its not present? 

See this issue for a similar change made in ErrorPageFilter of SpringBoot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for my problem described here [favicon.ico not found error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413304/favicon-ico-not-found-error).

But I don`t explicitly use URL /favicon in my views. 
I found out that grails tag  adds hidden fields for SYNCHRONIZER_TOKEN and SYNCHRONIZER_URL. And here the URL "/favicon.ico" was.

Answer (score 0):

There is something that is causing one side of the TCP connection between your client and server to be closed while the other side continues sending data. I've had this happen often when refreshing a webpage powered by a grails app and clicking the "X" button to cancel the reload while it is loading data.

When grails is running on windows, the exception you post will have the last exception (the root cause) say "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine". This comes from the [WSAECONNABORTED error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14305484) inside [WinSock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsock) (the windows sockets api, I made a more detailed answer about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682820/3033386)).

From my experimentation on a Linux system with a python script that can recreate this root cause, this issue manifested itself as a `broken pipe` error. Regardless of which system/root cause you have, Groovy/Grails will produce mostly the same stack trace as this error filters up the chain and manifests this as the `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error applying layout` that you observe.